# limiting number of rows of text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, text, format

is it possible to check (and how) to check the number of rows you have of a text?
If I use simple_format for some text, it does the line breaks, but what I need is it to check that there are no more than 3 lines of text.

code:

```
<%= simple_format haiku.content %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**simple_format** will insert <br /> when it encounters \n and <p></p> tags when it encounters \n\n. With this in mind, the following solution allows for flexibility of how the input string is built.

```
# split on 1 or more new line (\n)
lines = simple_format(haiku.content).split(/\n+/)

# check array size
lines.size <= 3
```